# Platform Developer 2

Tags: certification

In the last months Salesforce has changed the way to gain the Salesforce Platform Developer II. Besides the multichoice questions you have to complete four superbadges.

I completed my multichoice today and already have completed my Superbadges.

How do I connect my account(Trailhead account with my superbadges) so that I can get my fully completed Platform Developer 2 exam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce has a [knowledge base article](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Link-Your-Trailhead-and-Webassessor-Accounts) explaining the process. In summary, *they will contact you* within approximately one week (up to 8 business days) with instructions on what to do next. Once you complete the linking process, you wait again, up to approximately one week, and then they will issue the credential.

When I received mine a couple of months ago, Salesforce was issuing the certification itself on Wednesdays (it seems to be a manual process!). That may or may not still be the case.